# Pine64 fails to compress videos with ffmpeg and H264

Tags: ffmpeg, video, compression, armbian

I have a Pine64+ (1GB)  - A64-DB-Rev B (2016-02-24) with an All Winner Tech chip. I'd like to use to compress videos from 4K to 960. I installed Armbian using [these directions](https://github.com/pine64dev/PINE64-Installer/releases), I verified that `ffmpeg` is already installed. I mounted the USB drive with the videos and ran:

```
ffmpeg -i input.MP4 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=960:-1 -vb 1M output.MP4
```

It works and encodes 3 seconds of video. Then some messages show about "stopping", too quick for me to read, and the board shuts down.

I succeeded at this with a Raspberry Pi from 2018, so I know it's possible.

Is H264 encoding too demanding for this Pine64 board? If not, how can I use it to compress videos?

Comment: If you can capture the log output from ffmpeg it might show something informative: `ffmpeg -y -i input.MP4 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=960:-1 -vb 1M output.MP4 2> fflog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be high CPU usage. One solution for that is to [limit the number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565567/how-can-i-limit-ffmpeg-cpu-usage) with `-threads 1`. And that worked for this particular case and the compression went past the 3 second mark:

```
ffmpeg -i input.MP4 -threads 1 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=960:-1 -vb 1M output.MP4
```